# Working with Selenium, clicking on JS as href link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was hoping for maybe some clarification or suggestions on how to get selenium working with hyperlink. I have tried selecting it by pretty much every element possible. I have also attached a image with the source to look at and compare...

Example of html:

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-ACTION_COLUMN" id="5005a00001rJ22q_ACTION_COLUMN"><a href="javascript:srcUp(%27%2F5005a00001rJ22q%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F500%253Ffcf%253D00B5a00000AtOBk%2526rolodexIndex%253D-1%2526page%253D1%2526isdtp%253Dnv%26isdtp%3Dvw%27);"><span>Edit</span></a> | <a href="javascript: void(0);" title="Follow this case to receive updates in your feed." entityid="5005a00001rJ22q" class="chatterFollowUnfollowAction " revtitle="Stop following this case to stop receiving updates in your feed."></a></div>
```

Examples:

```
#clicky = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"javascript:srcUp(%27%2F5005a00001pKfzm%3Fisdtp%3Dvw%27);")]').click()

#clicky = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('javascript:srcUp(%27%2F5005a00001pKfzm%3Fisdtp%3Dvw%27);').click()

#clicky = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:srcUp(%27%2F5005a00001pKfzm%3Fisdtp%3Dvw%27);']").click()
```

Comment: You need to share HTML code in text format here, try to include bit more outer HTML

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: I have fixed it. And I can not post page since its only accessed through Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.//a[contains(@class,'chatterFollowUnfollowAction')]]//a[contains(@href,'javascript:srcUp')]").click()
```

In order to add an explicit wait before accessing this element use this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.//a[contains(@class,'chatterFollowUnfollowAction')]]//a[contains(@href,'javascript:srcUp')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you @Prophet 

I am getting this error.

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[.//a[contains(@class,'chatterFollowUnfollowAction')]]//a[contains(@href,'javascript:srcUp')]"}

Comment: I would like to add that there are 3-5 other href with the same characters. Not sure if that could be causing the issue.

Comment: This can be an issue. Also, the `href` and other attributes here may be dynamically changing and getting different values each time...

Comment: Yes that seems to be happening.. they may stay the same for a day or two but new ones will come in( This is a ticket system essentially)

Comment: It so we have to know more about this element. If it has some unique parent element so we can define some fixed, unique relationship between them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
someElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'chatterFollowUnfollowAction' and @title,'Follow this case')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",someElement)
```